# WebStorm cannot run JSX test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, webstorm, jsx

I cannot get tests in WebStorm to work for a React project I am working on.

I have the **JavaScript language version** set to **React JSX**, which means I have no compile errors.

Next I found a test example on the web and pasted it into a test file in my `/test` folder.

[image]

Magically some green arrows appear next to functions like `describe` and `it`. I click on one of these green arrows and run a test. Immediately I get this error :

```
/home/swe/Repositories/WebClient/code/tests/test2.js:21
          <div>
          ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

**Why am I getting this error?**

I am guessing that my compile JS is set to JSX, but whatever JavaScript is used by the test runner (I am thinking back to Java days) is using another JavaScript version.

I cannot find anything in the settings.

In fact I am not clear at all on how WebStorm uses testing. WebStorm recognises `describe` and `it`, which means, *I am guessing*, that WebStorm has Jasmine support.

In the settings I cannot find anything about Jasmine however. There is 
something about 'Karma' in the plugins panel. I am guessing that this plugin also uses Jasmine.

Comment: Runtime errors have absolutely nothing to do with Javascript language version - the latter is only used by IDE itself for code parsing, highlighting, etc. And your code is run not by the IDE, but by Node.js interpreter.

Comment: If WebStorm recognizes your test as Jest spec, it creates a Jest run configuration for it, and code is run with Jest runner. However, it uses default Jest configuration for this, which causes problems when using applications generated with create-react-app, for example - they require special configuration. If WebStorm fails to correctly detect the test runner to be used for your tests (because Jest was not found in dependencies list in your package.json), it tries to run your spec as a usual .js file - that, again, causes problems, as Node.js provides no support for JSX, and throws errors